# How to find required elements among multiple items in one list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, data-structures

I have a list which contains multiple filename:

```
example_list = ['2021-08-09_01.csv', '2021-08-09_02.csv', '2021-08-10_12.csv',
                '2021-08-10_03.csv']
```

I want to return a new list which includes the days that are inside the `example_list`:

```
new_list = ['09','10']
```

Regardless the number after the day string, what's the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: create new empy list, add all the files name splitted (use split() twice or see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56718450/how-can-i-split-between-two-characters-in-a-list-element-in-python for re.split) to get the day and then use set() to get each day just once

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a set comprehension where you slice the needed part from the string elements, and then (if actually needed) convert the created set into a
list:

```
example_list = ['2021-08-09_01.csv', '2021-08-09_02.csv', '2021-08-10_12.csv', '2021-08-10_03.csv']

new_list = list({elem[8:10] for elem in example_list})

print(new_list)
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> ['09', '10']
> ```

Comment: thanks for teaching me that: Alternately, a set can be defined with curly braces ({}):

Comment: @pippo1980 This *is* using curly braces?

Comment: yep : {elem[8:10] for elem in example_list} , I always thought about set just as set() , while {} to me, meant only empty dictionary

Comment: @pippo1980 Ah right right, now I get that I though you that :D

Comment: @pippo1980 Remember that an **empty** set must be defined with `set()`, otherwise it would clash with empty dict, only a non-empty set can use the `{"elem"}` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.split` to get the day string and then use `set()` to remove duplicates:

```py
new_list = list(set(s.split("-")[-1].split("_")[0] for s in example_list))
print(new_list)
```

Prints:

```py
['10', '09']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try like this.

Split the sub-string (`i[8:]`) at `_` and select the first item. Use a `set` to remove duplicates.

```
example_list = ['2021-08-09_01.csv', '2021-08-09_02.csv', '2021-08-10_12.csv', '2021-08-10_03.csv']

s = {i[8:].split('_')[0] for i in example_list}
print(list(s))
```

```
['09', '10']
```