# Getting the expressions inside a mathematical equation

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a equation I get in a file something like `(((2+1)*(4+5))/2)`. What I am looking for is the distinct mathematical expressions inside it.
In this case:
`2+1`
`4+5`
`(2+1)*(4+5)` and finally `((2+1)*(4+5))/2`.

I started by lookins at these [How can I split a string of a mathematical expressions in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43389684/how-can-i-split-a-string-of-a-mathematical-expressions-in-python)
But not able to arrive at a solution..

Can you please help.

Comment: Are you only concerned with parenthesis or does it need to be more complex?

Comment: Only the parenthesis. This are the kind of expression I am getting in my input files `ans = "((a+b)*c)+(b*a))"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a bare-bones parser by iterating through the string and each time you find an opening parenthesis, push the index to a stack. When you find a closing parenthesis, pop off the last thing the in the stack and take a slice from that to where you are now:

```
stack = []
s = "(((2+1)*(4+5))/2)"
for i, c in enumerate(s):
    if c == "(":
        stack.append(i+1)
    if c == ")":
        f = stack.pop()
        print(s[f:i])
```

**Result**

```
2+1
4+5
(2+1)*(4+5)
((2+1)*(4+5))/2
```

If `pop()` doesn't work or you have something left in the stack when you're done, you don't have balanced parenthesis — this can be fleshed out to do error checking.