# Seperate string character without function python

Tags: python, string, character, slice

Can you separate this "+2x-5y+8+2y"(there isnt any spaces between characters)
like [+2x,-5y,+8,+2y] in python? How?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43389684/how-can-i-split-a-string-of-a-mathematical-expressions-in-python/43389952

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  The complexity of a solution would depend on the pattern of expressions you want to parse.

Answer (score 0):

if you know the pattern of the input for all which might come in, take a look at [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

In your case, a solution could be something like

```py
import re
a = "+2x-5y+8+2y"
print(re.findall(r"[+-]\d[xy]?", a))
```

`re.findall(expression, input)` requires a regular expression and a argument which shall be parsed
In the above solution, the pattern `[+-]\d[xy]?` consists of

- `[+-]` either a + or a - symbol
- `\d` any digit, if you expect multiple digits use `\d+` instead (+ meaning here "at least one repetition")
- `[xy]?` one of the characters x and y, but it might be missing. If you expect other letters as well, add them inside these brackets